# due to which characters it does not work json_decode() ? - PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a javascript file with an array inside and I would like to include the javascript in a php file, extract the array and convert it to php.
Strangely `json_decode()` doesn't work, probably due to some characters.

Can you tell me which **characters** are not allowed and why?

```
$file_contents = 'var dati_login = [["1111","2021-10-30"],["_fbp=fb1111152; i18next=en-US; cookielaw_accepted=1; _ga=GA1.1.1111.1611118; e2sid=11115; _lr_uf_-qrlpn5=111-e111e-424c-9043-1111; _lr_tabs_-qrlpn5/e2={"sessionID":0,"recordingID":"111159d18955a","lastActivity":163480041112}; _lr_hb_-qrlpn5/e2={"heartbeat":1118402}; _ga_THFZJ5FYF8=GS1.1.11110.7.1.1111468.0","2021-10-30"]]';
$json_string = substr($file_contents,strpos($file_contents,'['));
$array_dati = json_decode($json_string);    //ecco l'array in php
print_r($array_dati);
```

but `json_decode()` not work...
i know the problem is in `array[1][0]` but i don't understan which characters....

Comment: Go to <https://jsonlint.com/> and find out for yourself

Answer (score 0):

you need to encode the inner data of $file_contents to \"

```
$file_contents = 'var dati_login = [["1111","2021-10-30"],["_fbp=fb1111152; i18next=en-US; cookielaw_accepted=1; _ga=GA1.1.1111.1611118; e2sid=11115; _lr_uf_-qrlpn5=111-e111e-424c-9043-1111; _lr_tabs_-qrlpn5/e2={\"sessionID\":0,\"recordingID\":\"111159d18955a\",\"lastActivity\":163480041112}; _lr_hb_-qrlpn5/e2={\"heartbeat\":1118402}; _ga_THFZJ5FYF8=GS1.1.11110.7.1.1111468.0","2021-10-30"]]';
```

Comment: ok but how can i do this with php ?

Comment: It is all the depend on what is the source of your data? who builds it? on what stage?